# How to publish a website remotely to IIS in C#

Tags: c#, iis, visual-studio-2008, publishing

Is there a way to publish a website/webservice/folder to the IIS directory of the remote machine?

If so how?

Comment: Do you want to public a C# site, or do you want your program to publish a site? Can you please be more explicit?

Comment: yes i want the website to programmatically publish a webservice actually

Answer (score 0):

Web Deploy sounds like the tool you want - you can also 'Publish' the site within VS 2010

http://www.iis.net/download/webdeploy